# ColdFusion server instance is taking too long to start

Tags: coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 2016 development edition. I have 3 instances configured and 3 applications in it. One of the applications is a big one, which uses multiple frameworks like ColdSpring, FW/1, FuseBox, MXUnit etc.

After a few days since I set up all these applications and started working, the instance which is configured for the large application is taking a long time to start. At first it was starting normally. But after a few days it is taking a very long time to start and even multiple tries to start the same.

I reinstalled ColdFusion and configured everything again. After a few days the same thing happens. Is there anything I can try to speed up the server start? Like clearing cache or anything like that? Because this keeps happening after a few days of working with the application.

Comment: The first step would be to find out why it is taking so long to startup. Check the server.log, coldfusion-out.log and coldfusion-error.log files for any errors.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/sometimes-coldfusion-services-refuse-to-start-normally-post-server-restart/) should help you. If you do not wish to save the class files, you can disable this feature in ColdFusion Administrator from **Server Settings>>Caching**